# bingo game using eclipse with pydev interpreter

Tags: python

Please, help me out in generating bingo game. I am using eclipse with "pydev" interpreter. till now i have worked this much. But I am not able to generate the matrix in a way, that 5 random numbers between 1-15 should be in 1st "COLUMN" and not in "ROW", similarly numbers between 16-30 in 2nd COLUMN, 31-45 in 3rd COLUMN, 46-60 in 4th COLUMN and finally 61-75 in 5th COLUMN. So, basically it becomes 5*5 matrix. My code generates the random numbers but not in the matrix form, i want.

```
import random
c1 = random.sample(range(1,15),5)
c2 = random.sample(range(16,30),5)
c3 = random.sample(range(31,45),5) 
c4 = random.sample(range(46,60),5)
c5 = random.sample(range(61,75),5)

matrix = [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5]  # why the ',' at the end of this line???

print(matrix)


for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        print("%s  "%(matrix[i][j], ) )
    break
print()

for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        print("%s  "%(matrix[i][j],) )    
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to have a range from 1 to 15, you need to use `range(1, 16)`, the second argument, called *stop*, is never included in the list. See the [range function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) in the documentation.

To answer your question, you can put your first list in the first column instead of the first row by using the `zip` function. See the [zip function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) in the documentation.

```
matrix = zip(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
```

And finally, you should learn a little more about Python syntax. It could really help you. It's designed to be simple. It's a really beautiful language, easy to read and easy to use. You can almost read every line as if it was English. Here is your loop rewritten:

```
for row in matrix:
    for item in row:
        print(item, end=" ")
        # Note the "end" argument, which replaces the newline by a space
    print()  # Newline at the end of the loop
```

[Learn more about for loops here.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

Comment: all the above runs when i try to make it run in python, but it doesn't work when I am trying to display the same thing in command prompt using the :  "connectionSocket.sendall(bytes(table))". Can someone please help me that?